# Почему криво переводит из windows1252 в UTF-8?

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

В общем пытаюсь обрабатывать кирилицу который получаю из PathVariable. Судя по тому какие были краказяблики то у меня как раз win-1252 (сижу от Ubuntu), весь код в том числе и JSP отмечены как UTF-8, в Maven так же отмечена кодировка UTF-8 и в конфиге Tomcat так же задана кодировка UTF-8 но по какой то причине отсылают вовсе не UTF-8. Судя из статьи по хабру мой тип краказябликов это win-1252. Я пытался перевести String из win-1252 в UTF-8 но переводит только часть букв (смотрите скриншот). Я всё перепробывал в том числе перевод из win-1251 в UTF-16 и различный вариации (BOM не пробывал). В общем ниже метод. А на скриншоте переменные при дебаге, пытался отправить слово "Привет"

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/rename/{album_name}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView renameAlbum(@PathVariable("album_name") String album_name, @RequestParam("new_album_name") String newAlbumName1252,RedirectAttributes attributes) throws Exception {
String newAlbumName = new String(newAlbumName1252.getBytes("windows-1252"),"UTF-8");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1252 - это не кириллица. Переводите из 1251

Comment: Хотя получается наоборот. У вас в переменной `newAlbumName1252` нечто очень похожее на UTF-8

Comment: по-моему, у вас кто-то где-то интерпретирует байты с текстом в `utf8`, как байты с текстом в `latin1` ([тест](http://ideone.com/8ybxxG))

Comment: в общем-то это [стандартное поведение](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q1) если в заголовках запроса не указана кодировка в `Content-Type:`. В Spring входит [специальный фильтр](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21409344/5661663) для установки кодировки тела запроса.

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось была кодировка ISO-8859-1. Из этой кодировки перевожу в UTF-8 всё великолепно работает